# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server internet not working after connected airtel dongle

Tags: 16.04, server, lts

Installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server in desktop , while connecting airtel dongle to get internet, internet is not working

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co.,Ltd E353/E3131(Mass Storage Mode)
```

How to resolve this please help me?

Comment: Which one? Please connect it and in terminal run `lsusb`. Edit the question and post the relevant line.

Comment: After connecting dongle ran this command lsusb,Here is the output for lsusb: Bus 001 Device 002: ID l2d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co.,Ltd E353/E3131(Mass Storage Mode)

Comment: I just edited your question with that info. In future please do it yourself, do not leave relevant info only in comments.

Comment: This should help understand what's needed for a Ubuntu Server: https://trick77.com/setting-up-huawei-e3276-150-4g-lte-usb-modem-ubuntu-server-desktop/ . Adapt accordingly. OBS: there's a mistake in your output, the Vendor ID is **12d1**, not l2d1. Keep that in mind when using the commands.

Comment: Thanks Celtic for your valuable reply, tried to download utility usb-modeswitch in pendrive to install updated device id and vendor id to fetch but its not installing and internet is not working,